# Custom function that takes inputs like np.dot

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to write a function `f` that takes an arbitrary function `g` with the signature `g : R^n -> R^n -> int` that "lifts" `g` so that it operates on `(R^{nxm}, R^{kxm})` by behaving like a dot product. Meaning I want `f` to have the signature `f : R^{nxm} -> R^{mxk} -> R^{nxk}` by applying `g` to all pairs of rows and columns in constructing a matrix `M` where `M_ij = g(A[i,:], B[:,j])`.

Is that possible?

For example `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine` expects two vectors. Now I would lift `cosine` with `f`:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine

A = np.random.randint(0, 3, (3,4))
B = np.random.randint(0, 3, (5,4))

cosine_lifted = f(cosine)
cosine_lifted(A, B)
```

This would then produce the same output as

```
def sim(A, B):
    ignored_states = np.seterr(divide='raise')
    return 1 - np.divide(np.dot(A, B.T), np.outer(np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1), np.linalg.norm(B, axis=1)))
```

Which is the same as `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity` plus the `1 - blah` part.

But if there was not `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity`, I would have to implement this lifted version of `cosine` myself (which I of course did here...). But I don't want to do that for all function that behave basically the same as the dot product in regard to how they mechanically process their argument. Therefore, I would like o have this `f` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my other answer assuming your

```
np.dot(A, B.T)
```

with a (3,4) and (5,4) inputs was the primary `dot` functionality that you were trying to emulate.  In other words, (3,4), (4,5) => (3,5) with summation on the common size 4 dimension.  My answer showed how that 2d calculation can be performed with element-wise multiplications.

For what it's worth, `np.dot` gets much of its speed by passing the task to BLAS (or similar) optimized libraries.  These have been written in C or Fortran, and optimized by generations of numerical-analysis coders.

But your signature description may be talking about a different thing.  It's a bit confusing.

```
g : R^n -> R^n -> int
```

Does this mean that `g(x,y)` takes two (n,) shape arrays, and returns an integer?  And it can't be generalized to work with 2d arrays?

```
f : R^{nxm} -> R^{kxm} -> R^{nxm}
```

Does this mean `f(A, B)` takes a (n,m) shape, and a (k,m) shape, and returns a (n,m) shape?  What happened to the `k` shape?  Is that `k` a typo?

Alternatively you talk about doing (I believe)

```
M = np.zeros((N,N))    # (N,M) ok?
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):    
        x = A[i,:]; y = B[:,j]
        M[i,j] = g(x, y)
```

alternatively:

```
M = np.array([[g(x,y) for y in B.T] for x in A])
```

Assuming `g` is a python function that can only work with 2 1d arrays (of matching length), and cannot be generalized to 2d arrays, there isn't any mechanism in `numpy` to `compile` the above double loop.  `g` has to be evaluated N**2 times.  And assuming `g` is not trivial, those N*2 evaluations will dominate the total evaluation time, not the iteration mechanism.

`np.vectorize` normally takes a function that accepts scalar inputs, but with a `signature` parameter it can work with your `g`:

```
 f = np.vectorize(g, signature='(n),(n)')  # signature syntax may be wrong
 M = f(A, B.T)
```

but in my testing `vectorize` has always been slower than an explicit iteration.  With a signature it's even slower.  So I kind of hesitate even mentioning it.

Comment: Ok I see, so its not pssible. Thanks. And yes `k` was a typo. It was supposed to be `R^{nxm} -> R^{mxk} -> R^{nxk}`

Answer (score 0):

`matmul` has been cast as a `ufunc`, and formally has a signature. `np.dot` is an earlier version and doesn't have a signature.

But given 2d arrays, `np.dot` is effectively a broadcasted form of multiplication followed by summation, or 'sum of products':

```
In [587]: A = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                                               
In [588]: B = np.arange(8).reshape(2,4)                                                                

In [589]: np.dot(A, B.T)                                                                               
Out[589]: 
array([[ 14,  38],
       [ 38, 126],
       [ 62, 214]])
```

equivalent:

```
In [591]: (A[:,None,:]*B[None,:,:]).sum(axis=2)                                                        
Out[591]: 
array([[ 14,  38],
       [ 38, 126],
       [ 62, 214]])
```

Some find the `einsum` style of signature easier to follow:

```
In [594]: np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', A, B)                                                                 
Out[594]: 
array([[ 14,  38],
       [ 38, 126],
       [ 62, 214]])
```

where the repeated `j` signals `dot` like summation.

===

Illustrating the iteration in my other answer:

```
In [601]: def g(x,y): 
     ...:     return (x*y).sum() 
     ...:                                                                                              
In [602]: A.shape, B.shape                                                                             
Out[602]: ((3, 4), (2, 4))
In [603]: np.array([[g(x,y) for y in B] for x in A])                                                   
Out[603]: 
array([[ 14,  38],
       [ 38, 126],
       [ 62, 214]])
```

and the `vectorize` version:

```
In [614]: f = np.vectorize(g, signature='(n),(n)->()')                                                 
In [615]: f(A[:,None,:], B[None,:,:])                                                                  
Out[615]: 
array([[ 14,  38],
       [ 38, 126],
       [ 62, 214]])
```

comparative times:

```
In [616]: timeit f(A[:,None,:], B[None,:,:])                                                           
255 µs ± 6.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [617]: timeit np.array([[g(x,y) for y in B] for x in A])                                            
69.4 µs ± 116 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [618]: timeit np.dot(A, B.T)                                                                        
3.15 µs ± 128 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and using `@hans'` 2nd `lift`:

```
In [623]: h = lift(g)                                                                                  
In [624]: h(A,B.T)                                                                                     
Out[624]: 
array([[ 14.,  38.],
       [ 38., 126.],
       [ 62., 214.]])
In [625]: timeit h(A,B.T)                                                                              
102 µs ± 56.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Ok, how does that solve the problem of applying a generic function `g` to `A` and `B`?

Comment: You stressed wanting a `dot` like signature; and I was try to explain that that actually involves - short of writing some compiled code (in `numba` or `cython`).  `numpy` is like a LEGO set.  It has a large number stock block shapes that let you make something quickly.  But it does not include a molding machine to cast custom block shapes.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Are you saying what I want is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for a function with a signature as simple as what follows (able to multiply two matrices), or do you want to emulate the entire `np.dot` api surface?

```py
def lift(f):
  def dot(A, B):
    return np.array([[f(v,w) for w in zip(*B)] for v in A])
  return dot
```

A major source of inefficiency in the above code is the allocations for all the intermediate lists. Since we know the final return value those are easy to avoid:

```py
def lift(f):
  def dot(A, B):
    result = np.empty((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]))
    for i,v in enumerate(A):
      for j,w in enumerate(zip(*B)):
        result[i,j] = f(v,w)
    return result
  return dot
```

Loops are fairly expensive in Python, but since `f` is operating on `k` elements it seems reasonable to assume that this overhead is small. You could reduce it further by compiling with `pypy` or `cython`.

Comment: In principle yes. But  your code is not efficient, right? I suppose `np.dot` is optimized.

Comment: Not super efficient no. Assuming you're supplying `f` as a black box though rather than an AST-level thing that you could compile/inline/optimize, about all that you could do to increase efficiency is reduce allocations and do the looping outside of native python (e.g. with pypy or cython). Assuming the cost of `f` is large relative to a python loop though, you could get asymptotically comparable performance by just pre-allocating the returned array and then filling it up.

Comment: For a simple `g`, your two `lift` time about the same.

Comment: Yep, you'd notice the largest difference if `g` were a quick function (e.g. one that ignored input values). Since OP asked about efficiency, it felt relevant to point out the places which might be lacking in efficiency.